# An error while installing Kivy (ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have tried to install Kivy using the command `pip3 install kivy==1.11.1` in the command prompt after going throw all the steps of the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist). However, this thing appears to me

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\stem-luxor.desktop-uhafvv3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\STEM-Luxor.DESKTOP-UHAFVV3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a93tln0n\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\STEM-Luxor.DESKTOP-UHAFVV3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a93tln0n\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\STEM-Luxor.DESKTOP-UHAFVV3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2mc5qys6'
         cwd: C:\Users\STEM-Luxor.DESKTOP-UHAFVV3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a93tln0n\kivy\
    Complete output (408 lines):
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\stem-luxor.desktop-uhafvv3\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\STEM-Luxor.DESKTOP-UHAFVV3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-ffmc6f_q\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\STEM-Luxor.DESKTOP-UHAFVV3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-ffmc6f_q\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\STEM-Luxor.DESKTOP-UHAFVV3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-v8ey9hgh'
.
.
.
    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

(There is still part of the error I could not show since I hit the character limit and I do not know what is the important part of it so I deleted everything does not contain `ERROR` but there are some parts contain `WARNING`)
I have searched for `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.` and found some answers which didn't work for me (or I just did not understand since I am relatively new to python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try typing :

```
python -m pip install kivy==
```

or type this:

```
pip3 install kivy==
```

and hit ENTER than choose from versions the one thar can work for you...
i sugg: the latest one and for ur case today is 2.0.0rc2 or 2.0.0rc3

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem. However, I want to understand why this worked and the other version did not and also why something like this is not mentioned, or at least easy to reach, in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#)

Answer (score 1):

For py 3.8

```
pip3 install --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple kivy[base]
```

Answer (score 0):

pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/

try pasting the above in your command prompt. Found this solution after a long struggle.